# How to disable the on-hover color change in Highcharts?

Tags: colors, highcharts, hover

I am using the column charts for my project. I have written a custom function that colors each bar of the chart based upon its y value. This works fine when I initialize the chart. As I hover over the chart, the color of the bar goes back to the default and my custom colors never return.

I have tries disabling on hover but that doesn't seem to work. I don't want the color to change even when hovered over the bar. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are probably setting custom colors in a wrong way, could you show that? In general you should set for each column specific color this way: `series: [{ data: [{x: x-value, y: y-value, color: 'red' }] }]`

Comment: Hi Pawel, I am setting colors based on the y value criteria. Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/. Here when you hover over it, the color changes back to the default blue. Is there a way to disable this default behavior on hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are updating color in a wrong way, use `point.update()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/8/

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }]
    },function(chart){

        var max = 200;

        $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

            if(data.y > max)
                data.update({
                    color:'red'
                });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for [this option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.states.hover.enabled):

```
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-states-hover-enabled-column/).

**EDITS**

Instead of modifying the SVG directly to set your colors, do it within the api:

```
    var max = 200;
    var seriesData = $.map([107, 31, 635, 203, 2],function(datum, i){
        return {
            color: datum > max ? 'red' : '#2f7ed8',
            y: datum
        };
    });


  $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: seriesData
        }]
    });
```

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/7/).

Comment: Hi Mark: I have tried that option but it still changes my custom colors upon hovering over it the first time. I dont want to lose teh colors that I have customised based upon the y value of the bar

Comment: @ssp, I don't understand.  You want the first hover to change it to a custom color but then never change it again on subsequent hovers?

Comment: Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/     If you hover over it, it changes its color back to blue and then you cant get back the original colors you set with the function. I do not want to make any color change to the bars on hover

Comment: @ssp, you'd be better off changing the color within the highcharts api.  It'll never take kindly to you modify the SVG outside of it's control and this should be used as a last resort.  See updated answer.

Comment: HI mark, can you show the same example for multiple conditions - like if - else -if else? Also I am setting the color of the series based upon the y values of the two series on my chart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46025/discussion-between-ssp-and-mark)