# Avoid tooltips when printing a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a chart and when I use the print button on the right corner to print the chart, sometime it happens the case that the tooltips of the series will be displayed also in the printing chart:

[image]

This means when I point my mouse to the printing button and my series is drawn also near it, then the tooltip for this series will be displayed and when I print the chart, this tooltip will be also printed, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with http://jsfiddle.net/dnok2ut0/

Comment: for me yes, Halvor. Ex: http://s8.postimg.org/qyh8vf7n9/print_problem.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the tooltip using CSS. To achieve this, create some styles specific for printing: Any style defined within the `@media print` will only be applied when the page is printed.

```
@media print {
    ...
}
```

In your case, you want to hide the tooltip that in Highcharts is a `g` with class `highcharts-tooltip`. So you would need to add this to your CSS and then it won't print the tooltip even if it's visible when you requested to print the page:

```
@media print {
    .highcharts-tooltip { display:none; }
}
```

Then when you print, the tooltip will not be visible as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

---

Notice how although the tooltip is not visible anymore, the point that I had the mouse over when doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is still highlighted. Fixing that may be trickier.

From [Mark's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335208/3695983), in Highcharts you can add this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to avoid the point from highlighting... but the problem then is that it won't highlight even when you are not printing, so you may not want to add this second part.

Comment: thanks alvaro, it works for me. And I want to ask also that is it possible that I get rid of the print button on the right corner when printing ?